# Eliminating Duplicate Values using a row count

Tags: sql, duplicates, union, common-table-expression

I am using a row count to return value matching either 1 or 2.  I have a need to keep all values equal to 2.  However, some values with a row count of 1 are identical based on the column name I am attempting to filter on.  What I'm looking for is a method to keep the rows that have a count of two but exclude the rows with a count of one only if they have a row count 2.  In the below, example, I am returning the same salesorder with the ID of 528886 but would like to exclude the row as it has a row 2.

Query:

```
select * from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SalesOrderPostedID
    Order By SalesOrderPostedID) as RowNumber
    from cte5) c
    Where SalesOrderPostedID=528886
    and c.RowNumber=1
    Union all
    select * from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SalesOrderPostedID
    Order By SalesOrderPostedID) as RowNumber
    from cte5) c
    Where SalesOrderPostedID=528886
    and c.RowNumber=2
```

I have attached the result.

[image]

---

Solution as provided by Gorgon with a slight modification.  The query below returns all rows with a count or two or any row that has a count of only one.

select c.*
from (select cte5.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by SalesOrderPostedID
                                Order By SalesOrderPostedID
                               ) as RowNumber,
             count(*) over (partition by SalesOrderPostedID) as cnt
     from cte5
    ) c
where (RowNumber = 2 or
      cnt = 1);

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I can't really follow the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you just doing this?

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by SalesOrderPostedID
                                Order By SalesOrderPostedID
                               ) as RowNumber
     from cte5
    ) c
where SalesOrderPostedID = 528886 and c.RowNumber <= 2;
```

If you then want only pairs of rows, then use:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by SalesOrderPostedID
                                Order By SalesOrderPostedID
                               ) as RowNumber,
             count(*) over (partition by SalesOrderPostedID) as cnt
     from cte5
    ) c
where SalesOrderPostedID = 528886 and RowNumber <= 2 and
      cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank You for your assistance.  This was exactly what we needed.

Respectfully